# Understanding failing TCP connectioon

Tags: websocket, tcp, wireshark, raspberry-pi-pico

### Setup

- Laptop (192.168.137.1)
- Pico W (192.168.137.142)
- Websocket is established between the Laptop and Pico W, and data is send from the Pico W to the laptop.
- I am using my own custom Websocket library which uses [this AsyncTCP library](https://github.com/khoih-prog/AsyncTCP_RP2040W/).

### The problem

After a while (15 seconds to a few minutes) my TCP connection starts to crumble and the tcp send buffer on my Pico W runs full. This is very repeatable, an example [Image of the WireShark capture on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbNyW.png).

What it looks like to me is that my pico W fails to receive an ACK for packet no. 1637. Which just looks like my connection has been lost. However, the weird thing is that afterwards there are no problems with sending a Keep-Alive (ACK) packet back and forth, which indicates that the connection has not been lost.

### What I expected

I expected that either the connection completely dies (no more communication) or that eventually the connection recovers (paacket no. 1637 is ACKed). But not that the communication is kept alive without resolving the failed ACK of no. 1637.

Where lies the problem? And what are suggested approaches to fix this problem?